# Tax question and deposit

Tags: united-states, taxes, india

If I earn income from a company in the US and live in India or overseas do I have to pay taxes

Can I ask to deposit the income in my US account where I lived before or into my India account

Answer (score 1):

> If I earn income from a company in the US and live in India or overseas do I have to pay taxes

Yes you have to pay taxes in India. You have to declare this as income and pay taxes as per your tax brackets.

> Can I ask to deposit the income in my US account where I lived before or into my India account

This is not relevant from Tax point of view. You can get the funds where ever its convenient. Even if you deposit in US account, this is still taxable in India.

Comment: If OP is a US citizen, OP also needs to pay taxes in the US.  However, tax treaties may mean that there are no taxes due when the return is filed.  That will depend on US/India tax treaties specifics.

Comment: @Xalorous Agreed. Citizenship and tax status in countries do matter to get a more accurate answer.